# What is the best datatype for storing a blogpost in SQL Server?

Tags: .net, sql-server

I´m using SQL Server and programming a blogtool.

I want to store texts longer than 4000 chars and a want it to be fast searchable.

Is ntext the right datatype to use?

Comment: I would rather use a search API, that look into indexed pages, to create a search box in my site, instead of developing my own searching algorithm. It's easy, try Google Search API for instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) - the text and ntext datatypes are deprecated and should no longer be used

Comment: What is the maximum length for nvarchar(max)?

Comment: Normally is 4000 chars, and 8000 for varchar, but it depends on the size of other columns in the same table I think

Comment: varchar(max) and nvarchar(max) should go up to 2GB - it is only available as of sql 2005

Answer (score 0):

Ray is correct - use Varchar(Max) or NVarchar(Max).  This supports data up to 2GB.